# Find unique and first instance of duplicate - copy to another row

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, unique, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to figure out the formula / coding for to list out all the uniques and first appearance / instance similar to how the "Remove Duplicates" add on is able to do it but I want it to be automated.

The Countifs formula on 'Data4' page is able to find the word "test" 4 times with different capitalization (which is what I want it to do) and then the page '4 Warnings' takes that data and I want that page to be able to filter out the the 3 other variations of the word "test" and spit it out into another column. If I am able to achieve this then I can eliminate duplicates of the same name but with different capitalization on the page 'Issued Warnings' under the D column.

Here is a link to a test google sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-85gZgs_bwIEdd0fZh0jdPdCaBGJAM145oR-qZw3dx4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(UPPER(Data4!B:B), Data4!E:E=TRUE))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That does work but I was hoping that it would not replace everything with uppercase (or lowercase) letters and would copy it in the same capitalization that the first instance the formula comes across is. If you were to view the spreadsheet and hit add-ons > remove duplicates > run scenario > 4 warnings it does what I am really looking for but I want that to be automatic and not have to be ran manually. However I will probably end up settling and get over everything being capitalized because the formula you answered does work for what I wanted. Thank for all of your help.

Comment: you can do: `=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(UPPER(Data4!B:B), Data4!E:E=TRUE)), Data4!B:B, 1, 0))` to return original state instead of upper case